# Javascript/AJAX Show Text in text file automatically

Tags: javascript, text

I am trying to make a simple AJAX program, that always displays the newest text from a file.
It should be retrieving it from the file, wait 2 seconds, and if something changed, write it out.
I tried already but the code doesn't seem to work.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function sleep()
        {
            var dt = new Date();
            dt.setTime(dt.getTime() + 2000);
            while (new Date().getTime() < dt.getTime());
        }
        function loadXMLDoc()
        {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
          }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxtest.txt",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    while (0=0)
     {
        loadXMLDoc();

    </script>
        <div id="myDiv"><h2>Status</h2></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout(loadXMLDoc(),1000)
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

How do I get it to check and update the text automatically?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

Here is the final code for anybody who is interested:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadXMLDoc()
        {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
          }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","status.txt",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        loadXMLDoc();
    </script>
    <div id="myDiv">Current Status</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        setInterval("loadXMLDoc()", 2000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You second and thrid <script> tag seems really odd. Didn't paste it right?

Comment: Don't try to write a `sleep()` function based on a `for` or `while` loop - it locks up the browser while it's running. Look into `setTimeout()` instead...

Comment: Ok, so I updated it and changed the script tag, and created a setTimeout. But why does it still not work?

Comment: Did you read any [documentation for `setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)? The first parameter needs to be a function reference, not a function call, so drop the parentheses after `loadXMLDoc()` and make it `setTimeout(loadXMLDoc,1000)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if its a typo or a thing from another language. (Like PHP)

In HTML you cannot have javascript code that goes across multiple script tags.

Also your while loop has only one = sign, would need two to be comparison.

But that being said you do want setTimeout or setInterval, because non multi-threaded javascript will just lockup, mulit-threaded ones would wasting processing time as well but not totally lockedup.

Something like

```
setInterval("loadXMLDoc()", 2000);
```

setTimeout executes the first parameter as javascript after the second parameter of milliseconds.

setInterval executes the like setTimeout except every X milliseconds.

Both setTimeout and setInterval return a value which can be used to stop the javascript from being executed again.

That value is used in `clearTimeout(value)` or `clearInterval(value)`

The body of your page would look like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="myDiv"><h2>Status</h2></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        setInterval("loadXMLDoc()", 2000);
    </script>
</body>
```